# Salesforce Bulk Job CSV Upload via Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp

Tags: rest, curl, google-apps-script, salesforce

I'm attempting to use Google Apps Script to access Salesforce's Bulk API 2.0 and [upload the CSV data to a job](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_bulk_v2.meta/api_bulk_v2/upload_job_data.htm), however Salesfore is returning

`[{"errorCode":"METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED","message":"HTTP Method 'GET' not allowed. Allowed are PUT"}]`

Given my experience with the Salesforce API, I highly doubt the issue is actually with the method type, but that there is some other validation which is causing this error. However, upon inspection of the request body and comparing it to what I *successfully* submit through cURL, I don't see what I can do to resolve.

The request code:

```
var headers = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer TOKEN"
};
var options = {
  "method": "put",
  "contentType": "text/csv",
  "headers": headers,
  "payload": "Id,Entity_Name__c\n001,One\n002,Two\n003,Three"
};
var url = INSTANCE + "/services/data/v44.0/jobs/ingest/" + JOB_ID + "/batches";
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Google Apps Script request as returned via [`getRequest()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#getrequesturl):

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer TOKEN"
  },
  "method": "put",
  "payload": "Id,Entity_Name__c\n001,One\n002,Two\n003,Three",
  "followRedirects": true,
  "validateHttpsCertificates": true,
  "useIntranet": false,
  "contentType": "text/csv",
  "url": "INSTANCE/services/data/v44.0/jobs/ingest/JOB_ID/batches"
}
```

cURL request:

```
curl --request PUT \
  --url INSTANCE/services/data/v44.0/jobs/ingest/JOB_ID/batches \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \
  --header 'content-type: text/csv' \
  --data '"Id,Entity_Name__c\n001,One\n002,Two\n003,Three"'
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: For example, how about modifying from ``"payload": "Id,Entity_Name__c\n001,One\n002,Two\n003,Three"`` to ``"payload": JSON.stringify("Id,Entity_Name__c\n001,One\n002,Two\n003,Three")``? I apologize I couldn't confirm whether this modification works in my environment.

Comment: @Tanaike Unfortunately, that does not affect the Salesforce response

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. For example, when ``"Accept": "application/json"`` or ``"Accept": "*/*"`` is added to the headers, will the response be changed?

Comment: @Tanaike Your suggestion is no inconvenience, however the resulting Salesforce response is, given that it still thinks the request is a GET.

Comment: When I tried your request to other server, ``"method": "PUT"`` is obtained. So it is found that the request uses PUT method. So although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, how about creating new Project and copying and pasting only the script for fetching, then running the script?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks. I will try that, but I think the issue is directly with how the Salesforce server is receiving the request and for some reason it interprets the cURL request differently from the GAS request.

Comment: As an additional information, when I tested your curl command, when it makes the request of curl be the same with the request of Google Apps Script, ``JSON.stringify("Id,Entity_Name__c\n001,One\n002,Two\n003,Three")`` and ``"Accept": "application/json"`` or ``"Accept": "*/*"`` were required.

Comment: I apologize I can only think of these modification points for now. If I found other modification points, I would like to report them.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for taking the time to help me figure it out! The issue persists for me.

Comment: Although I tried various situations, unfortunately, I couldn't obtain the situation that "GET" method is requested by using UrlFetchApp with ``"method": "put"``. From this result, I would like to propose to create new project and copy&paste only the script, and run the script again. But I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue. I apologize for this.